# How can i set an windows forms project to auto increment the version number, like it was in VB 6?

Tags: vb.net, build, vb6-migration

It was very practical to keep build number in VB6, as it auto-incremented that number every time that i "compiled" the program.

There is any equivalent feature in VB.Net? I am using VS 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an asterisk in the position you want autoincremented, in the My Project, Assembly Information dialog.